# Limiting Ground Overlay visibility to specific zoom levels in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming, overlay

Is there a way to limit the visibility of Ground Overlays in Google Maps to only certain zoom levels, say between 12 and 14.

In [Google's example](https://jsfiddle.net/ko2c8L80/) shown in their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple), the Ground Overlay displays at all zoom levels.
Here is their code:

```
var historicalOverlay;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18}
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 40.773941,
    south: 40.712216,
    east: -74.12544,
    west: -74.22655
  };

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
      imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a vote down without explanation? I think the question is clear and I couldn't find a clear answer elsewhere despite a lot of searching. Some of you may have 1000s of reputation points but my humble collection is precious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to the [map on the 'zoom_changed` event (documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map):

> zoom_changed | Arguments:  None
>   This event is fired when the map zoom property changes.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  if ((zoom > 12) && (zoom < 15)) {
    historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
  } else {
    historicalOverlay.setMap(null);
  }
});
```

```js
var historicalOverlay;
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 40.740,
      lng: -74.18
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = "zoom =" + map.getZoom();
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if ((zoom > 12) && (zoom < 15)) {
      historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
    } else {
      historicalOverlay.setMap(null);
    }
  })

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 40.773941,
    south: 40.712216,
    east: -74.12544,
    west: -74.22655
  };

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. I've tried to expand your script to include multiple states (like Image-A from 11 to 12, Image-B from 13 to 14 and Image-C from 15 to 16). What I found is that there's some inconsistent overlap depending if you are zooming in or zooming out. This is probably basic JavaScript syntax, but does `((zoom > 12) && (zoom < 15))` include both 12 and 15, or is it only 13 and 14?

Comment: 13 and 14; if you want it to include 12 and 15; you need to use >= and <=